# php for loop creating undefined variable for string values

Tags: php

I am looping though my data and strong the result in a variable. It is currently being stored as strings.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($AnotherArray); $i++){

  $myArray  .= $dataArray[$i].",";
 }
```

This correctly returns the content with commas separating the values. But i get a notice

```
Notice: undefind variable: $myArray in ...
```

The above is the first time i create and call $myArray

Comment: $myArray = .= , just .= would be enough and you should declare an string variable before the loop to avoid the warning $myArray = "";

Comment: Should be `$myArray .= $dataArray[$i].",";` you have an extra equals sign that is a syntax error

Comment: I had a typo, i removed the extra equals sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the variable defined before you can append to it

```
$myArray="";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($AnotherArray); $i++){

  $myArray  .= $dataArray[$i].",";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the `$myArray` variable first. So your code becomes:

```
$myArray = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($AnotherArray); $i++){
    $myArray .= $dataArray[$i].",";
}
```

As a side note, I'd also recommend looking at the naming of your variables, `$myArray` is actually a string, not an array. Also, `$dataArray` and `$AnotherArray` don't describe the data the variables are storing. When coding, it is useful to give variables meaningful names, so that yourself and others who may look at the code will find it easier to follow.